# Copying an image from one server to another using PHP

Tags: php, image, copy

I'm trying to copy an image from a remote server with the following code:

```
$src = "http://www.imagelocation.com/image.jpg";
$dest = "/server/location/upload/";
file_put_contents($dest, file_get_contents($src));
```

Unfortunately I keep getting the following error:

> Warning: file_put_contents(/server/location/upload/) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Is a directory in /server/location/myscript.php on line 220

Do you have any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$src = "http://www.imagelocation.com/image.jpg";
$dest = "/server/location/upload/" . basename($src);
file_put_contents($dest, file_get_contents($src));
```

You need to specify the filename. I added `basename($src)` which will write to the same filename that the original was. Be careful if you're copying from other directories, `basename()` only returns the filename so if you copy /image.jpg and /a/image.jpg you'll write over the original.

Comment: Perfect, the example really helps also. Thank you! On another note, how would I work out if the copy was successful or not?

Comment: use $check = file_put_contents($dest, file_get_contents($src));

and the look at the value of $check. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php says:

The function returns the number of bytes that were written to the file, or FALSE on failure.

Answer (score 2):

This is because $dest is a directory, not a file. You could either manually specify the filename or use basename()

Comment: Thank you for explaining where I went wrong. It was very useful!